# Google maps: Change colour of polyline when clicked, but change colour back to original colour when second polyline is clicked

Tags: google-maps

I have a site which has numerous hiking paths displayed as polylines in Google maps. All polylines have Strokecolor green as default. I would like it that when a polyline is clicked, the polyline colour turns red. It should remain red until a second (different) polyline is clicked. The first polyline should then turn back to green and the second polyline turns red.

I have searched and search and tried numerous solutions, but none work.

The "test" code I have submitted is "clean" without any of my failed attempts.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
          var map;
          var flightPath;
          var pathSymbol;
          function initMap() {
            pathSymbol = {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 4,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                scale: 3
            };

              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                  center: {lat: 45, lng: -87},
                  zoom: 6
              });

              var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                  { lat: 42.5, lng: -86.5 },
                  { lat: 42.5, lng: -87.5},
                  { lat: 43.5, lng: -88.5 },
                  { lat: 44.5, lng: -88.5 },
                  { lat: 46.5, lng: -89.5 },
                  { lat: 49.5, lng: -89.5 },
              ];
              var flightPlanCoordinates2 = [
                  { lat: 42, lng: -86 },
                  { lat: 42, lng: -87},
                  { lat: 42, lng: -88 },
                  { lat: 43, lng: -88 },
                  { lat: 44, lng: -89 },
                  { lat: 49, lng: -89 },
              ];
              var arrayOfFlightPlans = [flightPlanCoordinates, flightPlanCoordinates2];

              for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                  addPath({
                    path: arrayOfFlightPlans[i],
                    strokeColor: '#8CB65F',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 4,
                  });
                }
          }

          function addPath(props) {
            flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: props.path,
              strokeColor: props.strokeColor,
              strokeOpacity: props.strokeOpacity,
              strokeWeight: props.strokeWeight
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);

            flightPath.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
              this.setOptions({
                zIndex: 10,
                icons: [{
                  icon: pathSymbol,
                  offset: '0',
                  repeat: '40px',
                  zIndex: 10
                }],
              });
            });

            flightPath.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
              this.setOptions({
                zIndex: 0,
                icons: [{
                  visible: false,
                  zIndex: 0
                }],
              });
            });

          }
        </script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add  a  global var  .. previous path  and assign the object value when you click an object  then change the color for th actual object and restore th color for the prev_path object

```
var prev_path;


     flightPath.addListener('click', function(event) {

        this.setOptions({
            zIndex: 10,
            strokeColor: your_strokeColor,
            strokeOpacity: your_strokeOpacity,
            strokeWeight: your__strokeWeight 
            icons: [{
              icon: pathSymbol,
              offset: '0',
              repeat: '40px',
              zIndex: 10
            }],
          });

        if (prevPath){
          prev_path.setOptions({
              zIndex: 10,
            strokeColor: your_color_for_not_select_strokeColor,
            strokeOpacity: your_color_for_not_select_strokeOpacity,
            strokeWeight: your_color_for_not_select_strokeWeight 
          });
        }

        prev_path = this;

    });
```

Comment: Perfect. I have updated your code with an if - else there is no prev_path. Only once prev_path is assigned a value should it run through that code

Comment: Done. Great answer

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to keep references to all the polylines, process through that list setting them back to the default value on a click, then set the current polyline to the "selected color.

```
var polylines = [];
function addPath(props) {
  flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: props.path,
    strokeColor: props.strokeColor,
    strokeOpacity: props.strokeOpacity,
    strokeWeight: props.strokeWeight,
    normalOptions: {
      strokeColor: props.strokeColor,
    },
    selectedOptions: {
      strokeColor: "red",
    }
  });
  flightPath.setMap(map);
  polylines.push(flightPath);

  flightPath.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    this.setOptions({
      zIndex: 10,
      icons: [{
        icon: pathSymbol,
        offset: '0',
        repeat: '40px',
        zIndex: 10
      }],
    });
  });

  flightPath.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    this.setOptions({
     zIndex: 0,
      icons: [{
        visible: false,
        zIndex: 0
      }],
    });
  });
  flightPath.addListener('click', function(event) {
    for (var i=0; i<polylines.length; i++) {
      polylines[i].setOptions(polylines[i].normalOptions)
    }
    this.setOptions(this.selectedOptions);
  })
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jeuhy59n/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<style>
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  var flightPath;
  var pathSymbol;

  function initMap() {
    pathSymbol = {
      path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      strokeWeight: 4,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 3
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 45,
        lng: -87
      },
      zoom: 6
    });

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
      { lat: 42.5, lng: -86.5 },
      { lat: 42.5, lng: -87.5},
      { lat: 43.5, lng: -88.5 },
      { lat: 44.5, lng: -88.5 },
      { lat: 46.5, lng: -89.5 },
      { lat: 49.5, lng: -89.5 },
    ];
    var flightPlanCoordinates2 = [
      { lat: 42, lng: -86 },
      { lat: 42, lng: -87},
      { lat: 42, lng: -88 },
      { lat: 43, lng: -88 },
      { lat: 44, lng: -89 },
      { lat: 49, lng: -89 },
    ];
    var arrayOfFlightPlans = [flightPlanCoordinates, flightPlanCoordinates2];

    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      addPath({
        path: arrayOfFlightPlans[i],
        strokeColor: '#8CB65F',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 4,
      });
    }
  }
  var polylines = [];

  function addPath(props) {
    flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: props.path,
      strokeColor: props.strokeColor,
      strokeOpacity: props.strokeOpacity,
      strokeWeight: props.strokeWeight,
      normalOptions: {
        strokeColor: props.strokeColor,
      },
      selectedOptions: {
        strokeColor: "red",
      }
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
    polylines.push(flightPath);

    flightPath.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
      this.setOptions({
        zIndex: 10,
        icons: [{
          icon: pathSymbol,
          offset: '0',
          repeat: '40px',
          zIndex: 10
        }],
      });
    });

    flightPath.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
      this.setOptions({
        zIndex: 0,
        icons: [{
          visible: false,
          zIndex: 0
        }],
      });
    });
    flightPath.addListener('click', function(event) {
      for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
        polylines[i].setOptions(polylines[i].normalOptions)
      }
      this.setOptions(this.selectedOptions);
    })
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
</script>
```

Comment: This is great and has helped me with another problem. But I'll use the solution from scaisEdge - it's a little simpler. Thank you.